# Best method for processing sentences for if statements in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a voice to text program in python to run commands on my computer. My problem is I'm not sure if using regular expressions is the best way to handle the commands. The commands are broken down into two categories questions and actions and I check the first word for split that up. However I don't know how to filter down after that, for example given the command

> set an alarm for five thirty am

I first filter the first word as an action and move to my doActions function

```
def doAction(str2):
words = str2.split()
if words[0] == 'set':
    a = re.compile(' set an alarm for (\w+ \w*) (am|pm)')
    m = a.match(str2)
    if m:
         print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
         setAlarm(m.group(1), m.group(2))
     else:
         print(str2)
```

This works perfectly for this one command but it seems like it will be very inefficient to add more such as

> Start "program"
>
> Wake me up in 3 hours
>
> Go to sleep for a few hours

...

is there a better way of doing this that will be easier to add onto or is this already a better method than I realized. I'm pretty new to regular expressions so there may be better expressions for what I'm attempting as well.

The actions

turn "direction" the volume

beep in "number" "unit"

beep every "number" "unit" "number" times

turn "on/off" "device"

start "program"

wake me up at "hour" "minute"? "today/tomorrow"

wake me up "today/tomorrow" at "hour" "minute"?

wake me up in "number" "unit"

wake me up in "number" "unit" and "number" "unit"

text "person"

I think I could probably make regex's for them but was under the impression they can be resource intensive. And should I build and compile the expressions outside the function if I'm going to be using them a lot?

Comment: If you're asking how to do natural language processing that's a **huge** task

Comment: I was hoping to avoid going that much into it... I only have about 20-30 commands it doesn't need to recognize all possible permutations of them.

Comment: You want to do voice recognition, but only the easy version?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have voice recognition through julius, now I'm just wanting to process commands. I might check into natural language processing after I get things working but it seems like it would be a pretty big project to tackle on its own.

Comment: You have to fully define the portions of the command. Example: ACTION / WHAT|WHO / WHEN. Once you do that, you can use regular expression in the form of a trie to match action and optional sub-part permutations. Show a breakdown of the list of each portion and we can do a regex for you.

Comment: A parser could be useful for constructing a DSL for the commands you need.  Maybe pydlstool could do it, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydsltool/0.2.0.  More general info on parsing with Python is at https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing.